# Whether a battery store energy or simply it makes energy?

Tags: batteries

There're some easy concepts which I don't get exactly in my mind. I've been studying these things for two years of my engineering but they still bother me. Battery is one of them. Can someone explain?

- Whether a battery store energy or simply it makes energy?

I have searched it on Google and Yahoo but didn't find any helpful thing there (for me). So I will be glad if I got my problem solved here.

P.S. I hope that the question would not again be an off-topic, as it always does and moreover people don't suggest then where to go. It's a real sad thing.

Comment: It's not so much that these are off-topic (well, (2) is about electronics/engineering, not physics). It's that you are asking three entirely unrelated, broad questions. This is not a forum, and it is certainly not Yahoo answers ;) Take a look at our [about page](http://physics.stackexchange.com/about) - here, like all Stackexchange sites, we want to build up a collection of specific, well-posed questions that will be of help to future users (which also means that often the questions you have have already been answered if you search around).

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, a capacitor stores the electric charge. If the capacitance is $C$, then it stores the charge $Q$ and $C=Q/V$ where $V$ is the voltage. What is difficult to get for a capacitor is a high enough $C=Q/V$ i.e. a small voltage for a fixed charge $Q$. This is achieved by having two parallel plates. One of them gets positively charged, the other gets negatively charged, and the energy one needs to achieve this charge is low (and the voltage is low) if the plates are sufficiently large and if they're sufficiently close to one another. See [capacitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor).

2) They usually have some transformer that converts the alternating current to some internal direct current etc. If you attach it to direct current, the transformer will produce no energy (because it produces the energy from changes of the voltage, and they're zero) and nothing will happen. However, when there's something else connected directly to the power outlet and you connect it to the direct current, you may burn the circuits etc. It depends on the precise model.

3) Battery stores energy in the chemical form – that's different from a capacitor that stores the energy in the electrostatic field. Effectively, the electrons are being redistributed in the atoms and molecules during the chemical reactions and they're dropping a lower electrostatic potential level. By reducing their energy, they may pump the energy to the circuit. See [battery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_%28electricity%29).

Comment: Capacitors don't store electric charge, capacitors store energy.  As you write, the charge Q is the amount of charge on one plate while the other plate has -Q charge.  So, contrary to the first sentence, no electric charge is stored.  Instead, electric charge is *separated* and the energy required to do that is the energy that is stored.

Comment: Both plates are storing electric charge. The purpose of the capacitor is that this charge flows from one plate to another not through the interior of the capacitor but through the rest of the circuit, just like if the charge were stored at two completely different places. That's why a charged capacitor is able to produce current so that $\int dt\,I = Q$ is the charge of the capacitor. That's why we talk about the charge $Q$ of the capacitor at all. Your criticism is both nitpicking and morally wrong.

Comment: It's neither nitpicking nor morally wrong.  We often talk of "charging" a (rechargeable) battery and we do that in the same way we "charge" a capacitor - via a *current*.  I believe it is not nitpicking to point out that there is no *net* electric charge stored in a *charged* battery just as there is no *net* electric charge stored in a *charged* capacitor.  There is, however, *energy* stored in both.